# change single file upload to multiple file upload in php

Tags: php, post, xml-rpc, odoo

Can anyone help me change my code from uploading a single file into multiple file upload? I tried many examples and can't seem to get it to work. ode below.

```
    <tr>
      <td>Add file:</td>
        <td><input  type="file" name="cv" size="chars" class="Form" />             
     </td> 
    </tr>

    <?php
    include("lib/xmlrpc.inc");
    include("settings.php");  
    include("header.php"); 


$post = $_POST;


    $client = new xmlrpc_client($serverUri.'common');

    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('login');
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($user, "string"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string"));


    $res =  &$client->send($msg);

    if(!$res->faultCode()){

        $val = $res->value();   
        $id = $val->scalarval();

        if (empty($id)){

            echo "Connection error = ";
            exit;
        }
        else
        {

            $client2 = new xmlrpc_client($serverUri.'object');

            $val = array ("name" => new xmlrpcval($post['subject'],"string"),
                          "email_from" => new xmlrpcval($post['email'], "string"),
                          "partner_name" => new xmlrpcval($post['name'], "string"),
                          "partner_phone" => new xmlrpcval($post['phone'], "string"),
                          "description" => new xmlrpcval($post['letter'], "string"),
                          "job_id" => new xmlrpcval($post['jobid'], "int")
                        );

            $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($id, "int"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("hr.applicant", "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($val, "struct"));


            $res2 = &$client2->send($msg);

            if(!$res2->faultCode())
            {
                $val2 = $res2->value()->scalarval();

                $tmp_name = $_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['cv']['name'];

                if(file_exists($tmp_name))
                {
                    // open the file for a binary read
                    $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
                    // read the file content into a variable
                    $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
                    // close the file
                    fclose($file);

                    // now we encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
                    $encodedFile = base64_encode($data);   

                    $valFile = array ("name" => new xmlrpcval($file_name,"string"),
                                  "datas" => new xmlrpcval($encodedFile, "string"),
                                  "datas_fname" => new xmlrpcval($file_name, "string"),
                                  "index_content" => new xmlrpcval("true", "string"),
                                  "res_model" => new xmlrpcval("hr.applicant", "string"),
                                  "res_id" => new xmlrpcval($val2, "int"),
                                );

                    $msgFile = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
                    $msgFile->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
                    $msgFile->addParam(new xmlrpcval($id, "int"));
                    $msgFile->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string"));
                    $msgFile->addParam(new xmlrpcval("ir.attachment", "string"));
                    $msgFile->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
                    $msgFile->addParam(new xmlrpcval($valFile, "struct"));                                    

                    $res2File = &$client2->send($msgFile);
                }

                echo 'Thanks for applying, Files (name of file to be added) are uploaded.<br />';
                echo '<a href="index.php">Back to start</a><br />';

            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br />Problem in message sending for create application";

            }
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br />Connection not established";
    }

include("footer.php");
?>

 <input name="cv" type="file" size="chars" class="Form" />
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your code in your question.

Comment: yes, I just added it now but went a  bit pear shaped.

Comment: And what have you tried to convert this? What didn't work when you tried it?

Comment: I tried examples I found like using Foreach(). Probably more due to my lack of knowledge. I basically would like to add more than one file at a time using one submit button.

Comment: Hi andrewsi, I find shutting my question rather obnoxious. As I stated, I am rather new to this forum and maybe a warning that if I do not change my question will result in a shut down would have been civil.

Comment: I voted to close your question before your code appeared. Once you've voted to close, there's no way to undo it; but I have nominated this for re-opening. Also, where do you state that you're new to this forum?

Comment: My bad, I wrote wrong about being new on the forum. Anywho let it go now.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on code I could use to replace my current code? Nothing seems to integrate with my current code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!-- IMPORTANT:  FORM's enctype must be "multipart/form-data" -->
<form action="upload-handler.php.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile1" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile2" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>

<?php foreach ($_FILES as $file) { ... }
```

Or if you're trying to get multiple files from a single input.

```
<!-- IMPORTANT:  FORM's enctype must be "multipart/form-data" -->
<form method="post" action="upload-handler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="userfiles[]" id="userfiles" type="file" multiple="" />
</form>

<?php foreach ($_FILES as $file) { ... }
```

Comment: The problem I have is with the foreach() function. Do you have a working example? I tried both ways you suggested but still can only load one file.

Comment: can you run `var_export($_FILES); die;` and post up the results? Are you sure this is wrapped in a form element?

Comment: I don't know how to run var_export($_FILES);die; where do I add this code? the form is in another file. I can try to upload it if you want

Comment: This is what I got when I added var_export($_FILES);                                                                                                      array ( 'cv' => array ( 'name' => 'hotsaucepepperpalace.gif', 'type' => 'image/gif', 'tmp_name' => 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php5A54.tmp', 'error' => 0, 'size' => 8241, ), )Thanks for your application
Back to start.

Comment: It doesn't look like its uploading multiples at this point, are you selecting multiple files to be uploaded? The reason your foreach isn't working is it does not have multiples to work on at this point.

Comment: Yes, need some help to put in multiples. Not getting it to workProbably need to put a new funtion in it's place. Any ideas? it's sort of urgent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = fopen('D:\wamp\www\splite\uploads\hard bounce 10.txt','r'); 
        $f = 1; //new file number
        while(!feof($handle))
        {
            $newfile = fopen('D:/wamp/www/splite/batches/'.$f.'txt','w'); //create new file to write to with file number
            for($i = 1; $i <= 5000; $i++) //for 5000 lines
            {
                $import = fgets($handle);
                print_r($import);
                fwrite($newfile,$import);
                if(feof($handle))
                {break;} //If file ends, break loop
            }
            fclose($newfile);
            //MySQL newfile insertion stuff goes here
            $f++; //Increment newfile number
        }
        fclose($handle);`enter code here`
```